# delete space only before and after first colon

Tags: shell, awk, sed

I have data in below format .

```
desc                          : ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2         AB 0987654
```

I need data below format

```
desc : ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2         AB 0987654
```

I tried using  awk but it changes it to wrong format, basically deleting space in between also.

```
 awk '$1=$1' sample.txt 
 desc : ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2 AB 0987654
```

I also tried using different awk but it also doesnt serve the purpose. Here also it adds extra space in output.

```
awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS=":"}{gsub(/^[ \t]+/,"",$2);gsub(/[ \t]+$/,"",$1)}1' sample.txt 
desc:ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2         AB 0987654
```

Can someone help me where I am going wrong . Number of spaces between desc and colon may change so I dont want to hardcode the space deletion.

Regards.

Answer (score 3):

I suggest with GNU sed:

```
sed 's/  *:  */ : /' file
```

Output:

```
desc : ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2         AB 0987654
```

Comment: *before and after first colon* => there can be multiple spaces even after the colon. So I think it should be `'s/  *: */ : /'`

Comment: The key is not *not* add the `/g` (global) flag, so it does only 1 substitution.

Comment: Also watch out for input that has more colons with spaces around them. The `awk` solution will fail then.

Comment: @PesaThe: Okay, I've removed my awk answer.

Answer (score 0):

If your Input_file is same as your shown sample then following `awk` solution may also help you in same.

```
awk '{sub(/ +: +/," : ")} 1'  Input_file
```

Output will be as follows.

```
desc : ABC 1234567 MNOPQRS 2         AB 0987654
```